# Showing a particular set is a basis for the vector space $\dfrac{F[x]}{I}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I need help showing $B=\{(x-2)^2+I,(x-2)+I, 1+I\}$ is a basis for the vector space $\frac{F[x]}{I}$ over some field $F$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by $(x-2)^3$ and scalar multiplication is defined in the obvious way.

I started by assuming $a((x-2)^2+I)+b((x-2)+I)+c(1+I)=0$ then after simplifing we have that this implies $ax^2+(b-4a)x+(4a+c)\in I$ but since non-zero polynomials in $I$ are degree $3$ it must be that $ax^2+(b-4a)x+(4a+c)=0$ and thus $a=0, b-4a=0,$ and  $4a+c=0$ which gives $a=b=c=0$. I think I have shown that $B$ consists of linearly independent vectots. Am I correct?

Also, I now need to show that the elements in $B$ span $\frac{F[x]}{I}$. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in showing that the elements of $B$ are linear indepedent. To prove that they span $F[x]/I$, use polynomial long division. Let $p \in F[x]$, write 
$$ p(x) = q(x)(x-2)^3 + r(x)\tag{1} $$
with $\deg r < 3$. Write 
$$ r(x) = ax^2 + bx + c $$
We now attempt to write $a$ as a linear combination of $(x-2)^i$, $i = 0,1,2$. The idea is, that as $(x-2)^2$ is the only term containing $x^2$ we must have $$ ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-2)^2+ \text{lower order terms}$$
subtracting, we have 
$$ ax^2 + bx + c - a(x-2)^2 = bx + c + 4ax - 4a = (b+4a)x + c-4a $$
Now we must match the $x$-term, with $(x-2)$, hence 
$$ ax^2 + bx + c - a(x-2)^2 - (b+4a)(x-2) = c-4a + 2(b+4a) $$
Sorting the terms gives 
$$ ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-2)^2 + (b+4a)(x-2) + (4a + 2b + c) $$
Now reduce $(1)$ modulo $I$.

Comment: What do you mean by "now reduce (1) modulo I"?

Comment: nm I understand.

Comment: I am getting $a(x-2)^2+(b+2a)(x-2)+c+2b=ax^2-2ax+bx+c$

Comment: $a(x-2)^2  + (b+2a)(x-2) + c + 2b = a(x^2 - 2x + 4) + bx - 2b +2ax -4a + bx +c+2b = ax^2 -2ax+2ax +4a -4a + bx +c + 2b-2b = a^2+bx+c$

Comment: $(x-2)^2=x^2-4x+4$

Comment: Ups, of course, will correct

Comment: If it is not a pain in the butt can you explain you process on that darivation. It is really what I was having a problem with.

Comment: Changed my answetr